# bash confirm dynamic values

Tags: bash

I have a bash script say `test.sh` and while executing manually say `sh test.sh`. First it will ask `y/n`,then if I give yes,again it will ask `y/n` and on the second yes, it will ask me to give a `server host-name` and once I give the host-name again it asks for a series of `y/n` and finally it will be successfully completed. I am curious to know how to automate like a silent installation.

I tried `echo y | sh test.sh...`  But the issue with this is that for the server host-name also it is giving `y`

Comment: its not a duplicate.. here the values are dynamic.. please read the qn properly before commenting something

Comment: @PesaThe I reopened the question, feel free to add the snippet as an answer. gosatrini: I missed the part where you have to give a server name as input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
{ cat <<'EOF'
y
y
Some hostname
EOF
yes; } | ./test.sh
```

Or use `yes` / `echo` instead of the here-document:

```
{ yes | head -n 2; echo "Some hostname"; yes; } | ./test.sh
```

Comment: hi pesa is it possible to do like this {
a = server1
cat <<'EOF'
y
y
$a
EOF                      
yes; } | ./test.sh  i need the value of a to come there..

Comment: @gosatriani Yes, all you need to do is to remove the quotes around `EOF` and then variables will be expanded or use the second code :)

Comment: @gosatriani make sure there are no spaces around `=`: `a=server1`.

Comment: @gosatriani Why use a variable at all here?